Downloading Files from Azure File Share C# .NET Framework 4.8 (Getting error from ShareDirectoryClient crashes when subdirectory detected)
I can download all Files from Azure File share when there are no sub directories, but whenever subdirectory is within the directory, the code crashes to error:
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:0ccda3e3-d01a-00ae-42a5-21fad0000000
Time:2024-10-18T21:31:20.6046993Z
Status: 404 (The specified resource does not exist.)
ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound

Code: (What I tried to do is use item.IsDirectory but that doesn't skip over directories)
 public void DownloadALlFiles()
 {

    
         // Get a connection string to our Azure Storage account.
         string connectionString = "connectionstring";

         // Get a reference to a share named "sample-share"
         ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, "clientshare");

     // Get a reference to a directory named "sample-dir"
      ShareDirectoryClient dir = share.GetDirectoryClient("directory/");


    

         foreach (ShareFileItem item in dir.GetFilesAndDirectories())
         {

             Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
             // Get a reference to a file named "sample-file" in directory "sample-dir"
             ShareFileClient file = dir.GetFileClient(item.Name);

             // Download the file
            
             ShareFileDownloadInfo download = file.Download();

             using (FileStream stream = File.Open("localpath"+ item.Name, FileMode.CreateNew))
             {
                 download.Content.CopyTo(stream);
                 stream.FlushAsync();
                 stream.Close();
             }
         

            // await file.DeleteAsync();
         }

         //Console.ReadLine();
     
 }


Let me elaborate, so I want to download just the files ignoring the subdirectory. When, there is no subdirectories present, the code downloads all files just fine. But, whenever a sub directory is there, it crashes with error show above. I eliminated the access issue, and other issues that might be a common one.
I tried to use the following code to skip over directory, but this is also skipping over the files.
if (item.IsDirectory)
{

}

I am pretty sure that using item.IsDirectory is a solution to this, but I do not how to effectively integrate it.

Your issue is simply a question of creating a method that can then be called recursively in order to handle subdirectories, for example:
public void DownloadFiles(ShareDirectoryClient dir) 
{
   foreach (ShareFileItem it in dir.GetFilesAndDirectories()) 
      {
         if (it.IsDirectory)
         {
            ShareDirectoryClient subDir = dir.GetSubdirectoryClient(item.Name); // According to the SDK documentation, you're going to need to use this to get a ShareDirectoryClient that can handle the sub-directory insidide the parent.
            string subPath = Path.Combine("localpath", item.Name);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath); // This should prepare the directory structure so you can actually successfully perform the download afterwards
            DownloadFiles(subDir, subPath); // Now, we call the method again, but, instead of feeding it the original ShareDirectoryClient used for the base directory, we're feeding it a client for the subdirectory.
         }
         else
         {
            // Your normal file download code for when you're dealing with an actual file and not a directory.
         }
      }
}

Thea idea is to create the method in a way that you'll be able to call it from inside the method itself in order to handle subdirectories correctly.
Hope this helps.

Thank you! This does get me going, but however it only downloads one file and it stops as it keeps downloading the same file, and not the others.
Download code:
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.DownloadPath + item.Name, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
download.Content.CopyTo(stream);
 stream.FlushAsync();
 stream.Close();
 i++;

}
